# How to print offset of a Pickled Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

Here is my code:

```
Dictionary format:
index["help"] = [5,[3,5,12,78]]
index["time"] = [2,[13,205]]

// format of dictionary: index[term] = [frequency, [posting list]]

a_file = open("index_data.dict", "wb")
pickle.dump(index, a_file,-1)
a_file.close()

read_index = open("index_data.dict", "rb")
output = pickle.load(read_index)
read_index.close()
```

Is there a way, when I print the dictionary after reading the pickled object, I can print the offset also **where offset in the index file is the number of bytes from the start of the file where the corresponding postings list starts**?

Comment: Do you mean something like `print(read_index.tell())` ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.tell

Comment: I need to make a function which will print as print (term, frequency, offset)  where the offset is the position of the posting list from the  starting of the file.